# Difference between lambda and def method_name in Ruby

Tags: ruby, function, lambda

I am reading along in pickaxe 1.9 and the author uses lambda like this:

```
bo = lambda {|param| puts "You called me with #{param}"}
bo.call 99     => 'You called me with 99'
bo.call "cat"  => 'You called me with cat'
```

My question is this:  How is this any better/worse/different than just defining a method that does that same thing? Like so:

```
def bo(param)
  puts "You called me with #{param}"
end

bo("hello") => 'You called me with hello'
```

To me the lambda syntax seems much more confusing and spaghetti-like.

Comment: Also lambda is a special Proc. It is not a method.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Lambdas:

- are variations of [`Proc`s](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Proc.html),
- can be converted to/from [blocks](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_containers.html#S2),
- do not begin a new [closure scope](http://innig.net/software/ruby/closures-in-ruby) (meaning you can access variables defined outside the scope of your lambda, unlike `def`),
- can be passed around as variables.

I recommend checking out [this article](http://www.robertsosinski.com/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas/) that explain procs, blocks, and lambdas.

Edit: This link is outdated. For future reference, try [this article](http://awaxman11.github.io/blog/2013/08/05/what-is-the-difference-between-a-block/)

Comment: Great simple answer! This is everything that I am looking for

Answer (score 3):

The advantage that defining a lambda gives you is that you can then pass that lambda object as an attribute to another method.

```
def method1 &b
  #... some code
  b.call
end

def method2 &b
  #... some more code...
  b.call
end

def method3 &b
  b.call
  #even more code here
end

myCallback = lambda { "this is a callback that can be called from several methods"}
```

You can then use it like this:

```
method1 &myCallback
method2 &myCallback
method3 &myCallback
```

And the beauty of this, is that you only wrote of code of the callback once, but used it 3 times....

I would recommend you take a look at this [link](http://www.robertsosinski.com/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas/) for further reading :)

Comment: in the case of blocks, you can also use `yield` instead of `block.call`. This is in fact preferred as it's a good bit faster.